# How do you add a fog effect or make certain things seem farther away?

Tags: rendering

[image]

Like here in the background you can see the mountains fade out how do i do that?

Comment: Use a map value node. 25:36 in https://youtu.be/cyJQ99I5yUw

Comment: I absolutely love that pic. Who made it? (I assume that it wasn't you, since you're asking how to do it). And where did you find the original?

Answer (score 1):

There are at list 2 easy ways to accomplish that, one is while rendering, other is post-process the render. If you want to do it while rendering (will get slower render) you have to create a volumetric object, with volume absortion nodes (under material). To do on post process (will be faster) you have to activate while rendering the option "mist pass". After rendering, in the compositer, you can link the mist pass to your rendered images and set density, color, etc. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CxNeMMZs_sM

Comment: Consider if the link goes down, the answer becomes useless for future visitors. Please avoid pasting youtube/blenderartist links in order to maintain the quality of this page. Also users came here to get a **fast answer to a specific problem**, watching a video is time waste in most cases (IMO).

Answer (score 1):

Switch on the "Mist" pass in render layers settings.
You can then use this layer in the Compositor.
[image: here]