# How do I use 'mist' with Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

So I've been creating little projects for some time, but never actually got to use mist. Now that I need it I noticed it didn't want to work, even after reading multiple tutorials and forum posts.

I would have liked to upload my file, but for some reason it is 500mb.

Comment: WIthout more information is hard to help you. Please [edit]  your question and add images of your settings and explain in detailed what you currently have. Else, make a simplified version of your scene that holds only a few elements but that has the issue you are experiencing and upload for others to inspect.

Comment: related:http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65992/how-do-you-add-a-fog-effect-or-make-certain-things-seem-farther-away/65994#65994

Answer (score 3):

Change to Cycles.

Activate "Mist" under Renderlayers in "Passes".

Copy the node setup.

By the way, some faces of your rail face the wrong direction. Select the whole mesh in edit mode and press Ctrl-N. :-)

[image: Node setup, with result in left-bottom corner.]

Comment: The thing u have just said doensn t work for me

Comment: Could you please upload screenshots of your Cycles node setup and your world settings?

Comment: Here's the link:https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9ex8qtvkriu9qmo/AACb9PiACifBb_uvS50yaDRYa?dl=0
Allso, can you please tell me why can t I see the (cylinder;camera;etc) in the file I uploaded?
I know they are on other layers (first one) but I can t get to it

Comment: Allright. Firstivall, I don't know what you messed up in your scene, but I strongly recommend you to copy all of your mesh and past it into a new blender data. Then enable Cycles Rendering in the top bar. (Mist doesnt look that good in the Blender internal render) Then, in the Render Layers Tab select under passes, check the "mist" box. Under the World settings you can now set the distance, when your mist should start. Then, go to compositor (top bar, change default to compositing)

Comment: Then click the Render Layers icon (where the cursor in the picture is) and try reproducing the node setup in the picture. Add a node with Shift-A and then press Spacebar to search the node by name (should be the easiest way for you) By changing the size value of the map-node you can determine, how hard your mist is. I hope this helps, otherwise, tell me and I'll try to upload my scene for you :)

Comment: Thank you kindly for your answer. I ll try it after I finish my subway scene. :) still, can you please tell my why I can t find the other objects in the blender file I sent you? I can only see the "rails", but it s not the only thing I made. I just selected a new layer for more splace when I made the "rails" and now I can t find the other objects :p. It s judt half a meg.

Comment: Oh, wow, I didn t notice you allready did. Thank you so much :). I m so happy people like you are on these forums so that you can help noobies like me. I want to go to an arhitecture college, so i need to learn to model in 3d. help from guys like you is all i need for when I get stuck :)

Comment: Even though I m not *yet* good to video editing, I know lots in android programming, so add me on google plus (hangouts): "Dank Kush", maybe we ll help each other :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51563/discussion-between-50-shades-of-ubuntu-and-quacksilber).