# Cycles not adding mist pass on random frames in an animation?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation

I added a mist pass to a somewhat complex Blender scene yesterday. The compositing configuration is set up exactly like Quacksilber's reply here: [How do I use 'mist' with Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70834/how-do-i-use-mist-with-cycles/70881), and I am running Blender 2.81a on Windows.

The scene currently has 106 frames of animation, which is just a camera following a spline through the environment. Objects within the environment are not currently moving. When I render the animation, all of the frames render, but the mist pass is missing from some of them. There does not appear to be a pattern as to which frames will have mist and which won't. i.e. I have some sequences of 5+ frames in a row which all have the mist pass, but I also have sequences of 3-4 with no mist, as well as single frames alternating between mist/no mist. If I re-render the frames individually, they usually render correctly on the second attempt (and I've not found one that *never* renders correctly), so I can obtain the full animation sooner or later, but I'd be much happier if I didn't have to, because it's essentially doubling the render time.

The scene is complex enough that Blender uses 16GB of RAM while rendering in Cycles, but this is on a workstation with 32GB of RAM, so there's plenty left over. I have the camera set up to cull geometry further away than 35m, which should be the vast majority of the geometry in the scene, as it's a lot of low-poly-count terrain spread out over a large area.

Is this a known issue? Is it something I can work around/troubleshoot?

Comment: Sounds like a legit bug. Check developer.blender.org for bug reporting

Comment: OK, thank you. I created https://developer.blender.org/T74310.